# How to pass Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC) from one micro-service to another micro-service for one request?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, uuid, mdc

I'm using Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC) to logs unique key in logs and i'm getting the unique id for one request in the logs but problem is that i'm calling another micro-service to get some data so unique id in both service's logs is different.
so is there any way that i can print the same uuid in both service logs for one request ?? Because this is one request so should be same unique id also.

Ex: for understanding

one request come to first service

```java
// first micro-service running
method() {
  data = call second micro-service to fetch some data
  return response; // return response to request
}

// second micro-service running
methodSecond() {
  return firstServiceResponse; // return response to first service
}
```

I want both services to have the same uuid for one request in their service logs.